# ARM template for adding runbooks and modules

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group, azure-rm-template

Currently I am uploading manually custom modules for azure runtime automation runbooks in the azure portal. Then I also create manually a runbook which executes my custom module. I would like to do this via an ARM script.

I assume everything you can do in the azure portal, is also possible in ARM.

I am new to ARM, but deployed a website through ARM. That was relatively easy as I could just select Web App as resource. But in the Add Resource list, I can't find anything related to runbook or modules. Where can I find templates for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.  You could check this link: [Deploy Custom Azure Automation Integration Modules Using ARM Templates](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/11/26/deploy-custom-azure-automation-integration-modules-using-arm-templates/).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemas.microsoft.org/azure/deploymentTemplate?api-version=2015-01-01-preview#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0",
  "parameters": {
    "automationAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "New",
        "Existing"
      ]
    },
    "automationAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "moduleName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "moduleUri":{
      "type": "string"  
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "templatelink": "[concat('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rchaganti/armseries/master/', parameters('automationAccountType'), 'AccountTemplate.json')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "nestedTemplate",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('templatelink')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "accountName": {
            "value": "[parameters('automationAccountName')]"
          },
          "accountLocation": {
            "value": "[resourceGroup().Location]"
          },
          "moduleName": {
            "value": "[parameters('moduleName')]"
          },
          "moduleUri": {
            "value": "[parameters('moduleUri')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "templatelink": "[concat('https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/azureautomationpackages/templates%5Corigtemplates%5C', parameters('automationAccountType'), 'AccountTemplate.json')]"

What should I use here as template link? I get everytime an error telling me the template link is invalid.

Comment: The original nested template link is not available. I updated the post with right JSON. This now follows the same method as the PowerShell gallery to deploy modules to AA.

Check the updated post: http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/11/26/deploy-custom-azure-automation-integration-modules-using-arm-templates/

Comment: @ravikanth Thank you very much.  `"templatelink": "[concat('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rchaganti/armseries/master/', parameters('automationAccountType'), 'AccountTemplate.json')]"` works for me.

Comment: Is it also possible to do it without the external github url? I actually don't want my service to depend on an external dependency.

It also looks like the param ModuleUri is not accepting a local file source.
{\\\"module.properties.contentLink.uri\\\":[\\\"The uri field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or ftp URL.\\\"]}}

My Uri:
"ModuleUri": {
      "value": "file://C:/Source/MyModule.zip"
    }

Comment: @user1408786 Based on my knowledge, it is not possible. it could not be a local file. It supports https and http. I suggest you could save your module on Azure storage account if it is necessary.

Comment: Yup! The portal uploads the local zip to a temp location and deploys it.  Doing it directly from a local source in a template based deployment is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to not use the templatelink? So just in case the template gets removed or updated or anything, my ARM project still works.

Comment: @ravikanth  Is it also possible to not use the templatelink? So just in case the template gets removed or updated or anything, my ARM project still works.

Comment: @user1408786 You had better @ ravikanth. He is the of the blog and a PowerShell expert.

Comment: @user1408786 Yes, it is possible. Take a look at https://github.com/rchaganti/armseries.  You will see newautomationaccount.json and existingautomationaccount.json. Save them to your storage account.