# What am I supposed to put in URI parameter in ARM template for Automation module?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

As per documentation of Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/modules#ContentLink) it's expecting URI parameter. What exactly supposed to be at the end of that parameter? I want to push my custom module and it's possible through UI via ZIP file and I expected that I can specify ZIP with custom DSC resource but it did not work. There is no documentation I was able to find what shall appear in that URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide uri to your zipped dsc module ;) There are a bunch of article online that you can salvage data from. Like [this](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/11/26/deploy-custom-azure-automation-integration-modules-using-arm-templates/).

Also, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996904/arm-template-for-adding-runbooks-and-modules)

Comment: FYI, for anybody looking to implement this, it's not just ZIPped custom module, it does in fact requires some additional files. Details are available here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/authoring-integration-modules-for-azure-automation/)

Comment: Please note, however, that additional files are required only if you want to define a new Connection Type in the module. If you don't need that, just zip your custom module files.